# Trying to nest divs to make a button link inset instead of the others that are outsetted! Please help?

Tags: css, html

I am trying to nest divs so that I can make the page that I'm on inset instead of outset which the other ones are. This is what I have down so far. If anyone knows how to solve this, please tell me! Any help is appreciated!

This is my css code for it:

```
#LeftNav p {font-family: Arial;
font-size: 18px;
text-align: center;
padding: 10px;
margin-top: 65px;
margin-left: 4px;
margin-right: 4px;
position: relative;
border: 3px solid #000000;
border-style: outset;}

.Home_Inset {position: relative;
border: 3px solid #000000;
border-style: inset;}
```

Comment: I think you might need to give use the html as well

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.Home_Inset { border-style: inset !important; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! that worked after I put a p after .Home_Inset. That's been bugging me for ages, so thank you very much!

Comment: if it works with !important then it is simply an overriding style, either further down the stylesheet or with higher specificity. I would recommend rectifying the situation rather than applying this quick fix; it can lead to even more issues down the track.